# Rails sanitize remove default allowed tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sanitize

How would I use sanitize, but tell it to disallow some enabled by default tags? The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) states that I can put this in my `application.rb`

```
config.after_initialize do
  ActionView::Base.sanitized_allowed_tags.delete 'div'
end
```

Can I instead pass this as an argument to sanitize?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes you can specify which tags and attributes to allow on a per-call basis. From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize):

> Custom Use (only the mentioned tags and attributes are allowed, nothing else)
>
> ```
> <%= sanitize @article.body, :tags => %w(table tr td), :attributes => %w(id class style) %>
> ```

But the problem with that is that `:tags` has to include **all** the tags you want to allow.

The `sanitize` documentation says to

> See ActionView::Base for full docs on the available options.

but the documentation is a lie, `ActionView::Base` says nothing about the available options.

So, as usual, we have to go digging through the source and hope they don't silently change the interface. Tracing through the code a bit [yields this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/505e84599aff6abf719484636b0515e1ce2e2220/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/html-scanner/html/sanitizer.rb#L134):

```
def tokenize(text, options)
  options[:parent] = []
  options[:attributes] ||= allowed_attributes
  options[:tags]       ||= allowed_tags
  super
end

def process_node(node, result, options)
  result << case node
    when HTML::Tag
      if node.closing == :close
        options[:parent].shift
      else
        options[:parent].unshift node.name
      end

      process_attributes_for node, options

      options[:tags].include?(node.name) ? node : nil
    else
      bad_tags.include?(options[:parent].first) ? nil : node.to_s.gsub(/</, "&lt;")
  end
end
```

The default value for `options[:tags]` in `tokenize` and the way `options[:tags]` is used in `process_node` are of interest and tell us that if `options[:tags]` has anything then it has to include the entire set of allowed tags and there aren't any other options for controlling the tag set.

Also, if we look at `sanitize_helper.rb`, we see that [`sanitized_allowed_tags`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/50b2eb8cbd6cb923026b8fbb98482e06cdbd21ce/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb#L117) is just a wrapper for the `allowed_tags` in the whitelist sanitizer:

```
def sanitized_allowed_tags
  white_list_sanitizer.allowed_tags
end
```

You should be able to add your own helper that does something like this (untested off-the-top-of-my-head code):

```
def sensible_sanitize(html, options)
  if options.include? :not_tags
    options[:tags] = ActionView::Base.sanitized_allowed_tags - options[:not_tags]
  end
  sanitize html, options
end
```

and then you could

```
<%= sensible_sanitize @stuff, :not_tags => [ 'div' ] %>
```

to use the standard default tags except for `<div>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've used in my project and it has served me well. Unfortunately it doesn't work in Rails 6, as `#allowed_tags` is now a private method. I'll try to find alternative but want to let you know first

Answer (score 2):

I know you're looking for a way to pass the tags in, and for that mu's answer looks good!

I was keen to set them up globally which was trickier than I'd hoped as ActionView::Base has overridden sanitized_allowed_tags= to append rather than replace!

I ended up with the following to my application.rb:

```
SANITIZE_ALLOWED_TAGS = %w{a ul ol li b i}
config.after_initialize do
  ActionView::Base.sanitized_allowed_tags.clear
  ActionView::Base.sanitized_allowed_tags += SANITIZE_ALLOWED_TAGS
end
```