# strip_tags helper, tag/tags except with ruby on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

is it possible to make an exception with [strip_tags](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags), something like:

```
strip_tags("<b>Bold</b> no more! <div>hellooo</div>", :except => "<strong>")
```

or more of a tag

```
strip_tags("<b>Bold</b> no more! <div>hellooo</div>", :except => ["<strong>", "<div>"])
```

I would like to remove all tags from string except `<strong></strong>` tags.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Rails sanitize method directly (which is what strip_tags calls).

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize

```
# Custom Use (only the mentioned tags and attributes are allowed, nothing else)
<%= sanitize @article.body, tags: %w(table tr td), attributes: %w(id class style) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to be global, try adding this code to config/application.rb

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags = 'table', 'tr', 'td', 'strong', 'div'
end
```

Your method call would remain the same.

If you want it on a per-call basis, check out this answer:

[Rails sanitize remove default allowed tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542312/rails-sanitize-remove-default-allowed-tags)

There, you would create a new helper method that would do the same -- but all the extra nonsense would be in the helper method, and not on each call.